# Gatsby childImageSharp resolutions settings

Tags: gatsby

I'm using Gatsby graphyQl to set childImageSharp resolutions quality. 
When I run gatsby develop I get this error.

> Errors:   GraphQLError: Expected positive integer for height but
>   received 414.17910447761193 of type number

My graphy query has this as part of it.

```
   localFile {
        childImageSharp {
          resolutions(height: 200, quality: 60) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpResolutions_withWebp_noBase64
          }
        }
      }
```

I'm passing it a positive height value. Anyone have any ideas why I would be getting this ?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, this works for me, you might want to try it.

```
 {
     allFile {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
               fluid(maxWidth:1000){
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
        }
            }

          }
        }
      }
}
```